# Combobox SelectedItem.ToString() returns NULL when called outside of Main Class

Tags: c#, combobox, windows-forms-designer

I am just starting with c# coming from a mostly C based background so please be gentle. I am creating a Windows Form application and utilizing the Metro ModernUI package to create the form. I have created a main form with the designer, the main class inherits from the MetroForm class.

I have another class called PortTalk that inherits from the Main class. I have a method inside PortTalk that reads from a MetroComboBox on the form and converts the value to a string. The problem I am having is that SelectedItem.ToString() returns NULL even when there is a value selected.

Just FYI, I have a button that instantiates the PortTalk object and runs the method when clicked.

I have tried SelectedItem.ToString() outside of the PortTalk class and inside the Main class and this does return the expected value.

```
    public void SetPortBaudRate(int defaultPortBaudRate)
    {
        string baudRate;
        try
        {


        baudRate = metroComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString(); //this does not work
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(baudRate);

            if (baudRate == "")
            {
                baudRate = defaultPortBaudRate.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (System.NullReferenceException e)
        {
            MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Incorrect Baud!", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
        }
    }
```

See below for the button event handler:

```
    private void metroButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PortTalk _portTalk = new PortTalk();
        _portTalk.createPort();
        string tester = metroComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString(); //this works
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(tester);
    }
```

I had to modify the windows form designer code to change the declarations for the form objects from private to public in order to access them from my PortTalk class; could this be why I am getting problems? If so how can I properly access these objects from outside the Main class where the form is declared?

Also I have tried debugging and the viewer does show that SelectedItem does have the value that is in the combobox when I highlight over it, just ToString() returns NULL.

Just FYI below is from the Main class created by the windows form designer:

```
    public MetroFramework.Controls.MetroComboBox metroComboBox1; //modified
    public MetroFramework.Controls.MetroComboBox metroComboBox2; //modified
```

Comment: Prudence would dictate that in either case, you first check if there is anything selected before trying to use `ToString()`

Comment: Noted. Although would not change the outcome in this case.

Comment: The need to inherit your Form *again* seems a little fishy and a lot of details can be wrong there. Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: The Main class inherits from MetroForm and PortTalk inherits from Main. Can you explain why this is not a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Convert.ToString(defaultPortBaudRate)
```

Comment: @Gaurav Mall : what did you edit in my answer? Its exactly the same!

Comment: I just formatted the code. Now you can see that the `Convert.ToString(defaultPortBaudRate)` is code and not simple text :)